# how to subtract two columns which are times in access sql query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have two columns in one of the tables : `Arrival_Time` and `Leaving_Time`.
Both are time fields which are formatted like this: `HH:MM:SS`.

I want to subtract `Leaving_Time` from `Arrival_Time`, for example:

Arrival time: `02:00:00` 
Leaving_time: 02:45:00 = 45 minutes.

I tried this query :

```
SELECT  (Jobs.Leaving_time) - (Jobs.Arrival_Time) AS Time_Difference
FROM Technicians,Jobs, Tech_Allocation
WHERE Jobs.Job_ID=Tech_Allocation.Job_ID     
  AND Tech_Allocation.Technician_ID=Technicians.Technician_ID
ORDER BY  (Jobs.Leaving_time) - (Jobs.Arrival_Time) ASC;
```

The query runs but the results of the subtraction are shown in decimals not as minutes as I want them to be.

thank you

Comment: Shown as decimals? What is the acutal output?

Comment: this is an example of the output shown : 3.47222222222221E-03

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your question, you said you want the time duration displayed as minutes.  However in a comment, you said you want the result displayed as Hour:Minutes:Seconds.

Use the Format() function to display your float value as Hour:Minutes:Seconds.

```
SELECT Format(j.Leaving_time - j.Arrival_Time, "hh:nn:ss") AS Time_Difference
FROM Technicians AS t, Jobs AS j, Tech_Allocation AS ta
WHERE j.Job_ID = ta.Job_ID     
  AND ta.Technician_ID = t.Technician_ID
ORDER BY 1 ASC;
```

Beware, this approach is only valid for Time_Differences less than 24 hours.

Edit:

1. I used 1 in the ORDER BY to refer to the first item in the field list.  It's more convenient than writing the field expression in the ORDER BY.
2. You don't really need ASC in the ORDER BY here.
3. I would use Access' query designer to connect up the tables with INNER JOIN expressions, rather than the old-style WHERE approach.
4. Assigning short meaningful ALIASes for the tables can make the SQL more concise and easier for humans to comprehend.

Answer (score 3):

In Access, you'll want to look at [the DateDiff() function](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/datediff-function-HA001228811.aspx).

Comment: @Tantoon. DateDiff should work: `DateDiff('n',Jobs.Arrival_Time,Jobs.Leaving_time)`

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using MS Access, I found this MS Office discussion entitled [On time and how much has elapsed](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/on-time-and-how-much-has-elapsed-HA001110218.aspx). Please take a look and see if things like `totalminutes = Int(CSng(interval * 1440))` make sense.